# Does an exploit exist to enable Android debug mode on a locked phone?

Tags: android, exploit

Does someone know an exploit to activate the Android debug mode even if the phone is locked? 
I've tried some software to unlock but this is not the way I want to resolve it ...

Comment: This would be a huge security vulnerability if it existed. Unless someone decides to burn a zero day to answer your question, I don't think this is possible. Now, perhaps there is another method, but you have not included any information about your device in the question.

Comment: Your comment made me smile too much .Ok the version of android is 8.1.0  and it is for samsung , techno and infinix these marks

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not an exploit database or a forum to trade exploits.